# Why my entity framework dll is not loaded?

Tags: iis, entity

I'm deploying an application on a production server (so no visual studio installed locally).
I have a EntityFramework.dll in my bin folder.
But I keep getting a 500 error.

```
Cannot load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of his dependencies
```

The nuget page says it has no dependency.
I have .net framework 3.5 and 4.7

Any idea on what to look for ?

Comment: Have you exported this application by using Solution Explorer -> Project -> Right click -> Publish? I believe your application is looking for a .NET Framework version 4.4 but you are using a different version, I think you need to have those two alligned to avoid this issue

Comment: No I did not exported it from VS. I did not even developed it. I'm just moving it to a new server. It's working fine on the current server. I took the whole folder, copied it over, configure IIS. Like I said, I have the EntityFramework.dll in the bin folder. It's version 6.0.0.0. but 
1) it's up and running on the current server 2) I do not know where to get the vers 4.4.0.0 of the dll

Comment: I ended up changing the version to 6.0.0.0 in the web.config and it seems to work now :)